# Link object with dependencies

Tags: c++, linker, g++

my project tree:

```
./main.h
./main.cpp
./Makefile
./sources/myclass.cpp
./includes/myclass.h
./objects/

#./Makefile
BUILD = myexecutable

LDFLAGS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-system
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
RM = rm -rf

OBJECTS =  main.o $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), myclass.o)

OBJ_DIR = objects/
SRC_DIR = sources/

.PHONY: clean

all: clean $(BUILD)

$(BUILD): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BUILD) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< > $(OBJ_DIR)$*.d # New line for create myclass.d
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


clean:
    $(RM) $(BUILD) $(OBJ_DIR)*.o
```

when i try to run `make` i get this:

```
$ make
rm -rf myexecutable objects/*.o
g++ -MMD -Wall -c sources/myclass.cpp -o objects/myclass.o
g++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio  -lsfml-system -o myexecutable main.o objects/myclass.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `mynamespace::MyClass::method()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `mynamespace::MyClass::otherMethod()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x406): undefined reference to `mynamespace::MyClass::~MyClass()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x50e): undefined reference to `mynamespace::MyClass::~MyClass()'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [myexecutable] Error 1
```

**how to fix the main.o dependency of myclass.o?**

### Edit

i added a new line for create *.d dependency *.d files for i dont know how to use

Comment: Looks ok to me. Does `myclass.o` actually define those symbols?

Comment: yes. the myclass.o is create correctly

Comment: Did you check with `nm -C myclass.o` that it defines the symbols you believe?

Comment: i can see. thanks for the nm command. i see the error @BasileStarynkevitch. the error was the non implementation of these methods

Answer (score 0):

Correct to:

```
LIBES = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-system
$(BUILD): $(OBJECTS)
     $(CXX) -o $(BUILD) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBES)
```

The `LIBES` should replace `LDFLAGS` and the two lines for `BUILD` should be changed.

Order of linking matters a lot: put your object files, then the libraries from high-level to lowest-level system libraries.

Comment: Then you might need to reorder your libraries.